# How to give data from laravel to vue.js?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

When i start write application i used to laravel blade. But now i have to transfer all to vue js and i don't known how to give data from controllers to vue.js. Also i don't know how to transfer this code

```
@if(Session::has('error_text'))
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 formMessage">
            <div class="iw">
                <div class="text-error">{{Session::get('error_text')}}</div>
                @if(Session::has('with_link'))
                    <div class="help-text"><a href="{{Session::get('with_link')}}">{{Session::get('link_text')}}</a></div>
                @endif

                @if(Session::has('unknown_symbols'))
                    <div class="help-text"><a href="#">Report a bug</a></div>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: what do you mean transfer? Do you want to echo blade data in vuejs or viseversa?

Comment: exactly. I want to show data which gives controller

Answer (score 0):

In the blade file if you want to access the vue data you should use `@{{ item }}`. With the `@` sign before the interpolation you escape the blade templating.

To pass data from the laravel to vue itself, you should use JSON which you call from your Vue and assign it to a variabel.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by creating a component and assign the data with properties

```
<custom-component data="{{ $bladeVariable }}"></custom-component>
```